# Accessing a array the right way

Tags: php

I have this array: ($csv)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Spalte1] => datensazt1
            [Spalte 2] => datensatz1
            [Spalte 3] => datensatz1
            [Spalte 4] => datensatz1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Spalte1] => datensatz2
            [Spalte 2] => datensatz2
            [Spalte 3] => datensatz2
            [Spalte 4] => datensatz2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Spalte1] => datensatz3
            [Spalte 2] => datensatz3
            [Spalte 3] => datensatz3
            [Spalte 4] => datensatz3
        )
)
```

I want to access it like this:

```
csv[0]['Spalte1']
```

But I get the following error:

```
Undefined index: Spalte1 in
```

Can anyone explain me why? - The data is coming from a csv file.

Function to get the array of the csv file:

```
function csv_to_array($filename='', $delimiter=',')
{
    if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
        return FALSE;

    $header = NULL;
    $data = array();
    if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
    {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
        {
            if(!$header)
                $header = $row;
            else
                $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

This is my code I try to access the data:

```
 $csv = csv_to_array($upload_DIR . $_GET['fileName'], ';');
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($csv[0]['Spalte1']);
    echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Please show the code that receives the array and the actual code where you try to access it. The way you have done should work, provided the array contains what you expect it to at the time you access it.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Ok but what is returned into $csv? Can you dump and post it?

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Spalte1] => datensazt1
            [Spalte 2] => datensatz1
            [Spalte 3] => datensatz1
            [Spalte 4] => datensatz1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Spalte1] => datensatz2
            [Spalte 2] => datensatz2
            [Spalte 3] => datensatz2
            [Spalte 4] => datensatz2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Spalte1] => datensatz3
            [Spalte 2] => datensatz3
            [Spalte 3] => datensatz3
            [Spalte 4] => datensatz3
        )

)

Comment: In your question please. Nobody can read that in a comment

Comment: The Code snippet is also above. The first code block in the post

Comment: I would suggest you replace `print_r($csv[0]['Spalte1']);` with `print_r($csv);` and see what you get printed

Comment: Something is going wrong with `array_combine()`. It looks to me like you are getting a combination of the header row and current row for every row following the header as in `[header, header + row, header + row, header + row]`. Most likely solvable by doing `$data[] = $header` in the `if` and  `$data[] = $row` in the `else` case.  You'll be able to see it with `print_r($csv)`

Comment: array_combine was the problem. Thanks guys!